# Pygame の pygame.event.get() には押されたボタンの情報が順番に入っている？

Tags: python, pygame

`pygame.event.get()` について、概念的な質問です。公式ドキュメントには、"イベントキューから全てのイベント情報を〜" との記述がありますが、イベントキューには押されたボタンの情報が順番に入っているという認識でよろしいでしょうか。